# How to stop Parameter variaton experiment at certain variable value instead of time

Tags: anylogic

I am running a parameter variation experiment and would like to be able to stop at a variable value instead of at at specified time. In my simulation I have variable that counts whenever an agent passes through my zink. The variable is called Loads. I would like to stop the parameter variation experiment when Loads=16.

I have tried the "additional experiment stop condition", but can't seem to get it right.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/5cjSX.jpg

Answer (score 0):

You are mixing up 2 things, I think. You want to stop an *individual simulation run* when something in the model happens. You can easily do that using this code in your actual model (not in the experiment properties):

```
if (loads==16) getEngine().stop();
```

What you did was to define when the *parameter variation experiment* should stop. However, that condition is never satisfied (and it sounds like you don't want that).

Comment: i am running 100 replications and i would like to be able to  stop each expoeriment at 16 loads and proceed to the next one, instead of after the 12 hours that i currently have my modeltime set at.

Comment: Again, I think you mix up terms. If you want to stop a replication, use my code above at the relevant place in the model. Stopping an experiment (=all 100 replications) based on a model-specific characteristic does not make sense. And it seems your "loads" value is something inside the model, right?